# Why emberjs website says 56kb when it's actually 200KB?

Tags: ember.js

emberjs.com homepage says 56kb for minified version but when you actually download it it's over 200KB.

What is the correct size of the minified emberJs library?

Answer (score 2):

The minified version is in my opinion based on the compressed file size.

When I 7-zipped the JavaScript file, the size was compressed to 51KB and zipping it resulted in 56KB.

That's what Wikipedia says about minification:

> [...]Packer, for instance, can optionally Base64 compress the given source code in a manner that can be decompressed by regular web browsers[...]

So I think the 56KB are based on the compressed value.